# How do i convert Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() to int with c# in asp.net vs2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How do I convert Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() to an int.

code:

```
string clientId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
if (clientId != null) {
    cart NewInCart = new cart();
    NewInCart.ClientId = Convert.ToInt32(clientId);
}
```

Above code gives error stating:

> when converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.

Comment: it's telling you what to do are you familiar with the `DateTime.Parse || DateTime.TryParse || DateTime.ParseExact`  functions also your Title and your question are 2 different things. do you know how to use the debugger..? what is the value of `cliendId` when you step through the code using the debugger..?

Comment: Are you sure your newincart.clientid isn't somehow a date?  I would think that the .clientid on Identity is already an int.

Comment: I am sure that Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() returns a string not a date. When I assigned "-1" to clientId, the code works; but when I assign Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() it throws an error telling me that I am not formatting correctly (acting like I am trying to format a date which I am not ~ the text generated by Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() looks like: xx-45-rty-566-g45 etc). The issue is, how can I format Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() to an int correctly?

Comment: Grab the string returned from the call to GetUserId and let us have that...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
NewInCart.ClientId = Int32.Parse(clientId);
```

Comment: I have tried Int32.Parse(clientId); and int.Parse(clientId);  All giving the same error. Am I missing a using declaration?

Comment: @method man, the compiler thinks that Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() is a date. Essentially, the regular methos of formatting to int are not working.  int clientId = int.Parse(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId()); still gave the same error. Meanwhile Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() on its own is returning a string, but the compiler is refusing to format it to int.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted for now.

I have decided to change the data type of ClientID in the dbo to `nvarchar(50);` that way I save like this:

```
string clientId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() ;
.......
cart.ClientId = clientId;
```

where `cart.ClientId` is now expecting a string.  This sorted my problem and I no longer need to convert `Context.User.Identity.GetUserId()` to int.